# How can I set the value of a field to a value and then have it return to null after a delay?

Tags: angularjs

I have an AngularJS Service:

How can I set the value of a property to a value of "abc" and then have it return to null after 15 seconds.

```
var a = "abc";
...
a = null;
```

Comment: use `$timeout` in your service to reset that value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use $timeout in your service for resetting the value of that property.

In your service:

```
app.factory("MyFactory", function($timeout){
   var a = "abc";

   $timeout(function() {
      a = null;
   }, 15000);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I upvoted and I will accept your answer. Someone downvoted my question. I wonder why.

Comment: Am not sure, who down voted. But glad it helped you :)